# Linux Remote Home Mounting

Tags: linux, samba

So I have a samba share on my server that has a home directory /home/user/ which is being shared via the [homes] section in my samba server.  On my PC, I would like to mount my home directory so that my Documents, Pictures, Photos directories are accessible as if they were located on my local machine.  Problem is that my home directory on my local PC also has my wine folder, some other "." configuration folders, virtualbox containers, etc, that I would like to keep on my local PC and not have them be loaded across the network (i.e. wine folder... photoshop would take forever to load! =]).  It doesn't make much sense to me to move all of that stuff over to my server.

Should I mount each folder separately?  Or is there a way I can mount only a few of the directories within the remote share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use automount and symbolic links from /home/usr.  The remote directory is mounted as /homes/server where server is the name of the server from which I am mounting the directory.

I then use symbolic links on the remote hosts.  If you move the relevant directories to /homes/server/usr before exporting the directory, you will need symbolic links there too.  This is what I have done. /home/usr then should be limited to server local files.  I changed my samba homes export accordingly, and don't have the server local configuration files being exported to the Windows clients.

If you mount the share as H: you can move the relevant directories to the H: drive.  If it is done correctly, the registry keys get updated, and the move sticks.  Search for the directions for moving the directories to another drive.

Answer (score -1):

You can use 'veto files', as described here: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#VETOFILES

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question.  If I just veto'd files, I would still be mounting a... "less-full" version of the files on my server which isn't really what I'm looking to do.  I'm trying to mount only certain directories on my local machine.  My samba share is working fine.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking, then - the 'veto files' option covers directories too. Is it that you want to only include certain directories, rather than excluding a specified list?

Comment: On my local machine I have /home/user/.files, I do not want to map that to the server:/home/user because that will make all of my local stuff disappear.  What you're referring to is changing it so only certain directories are visible on the remote machine.  I only want specific folders to be mapped on my local machine.